# Is there a JavaScript equivalent to php's password_verify?

Tags: javascript, hash, cryptography, cryptojs

What I want to do is a small, local web app which stores notes in localStorage.
I want to hash the password, in php this would be`password_hash()`,and put it in localStorage either.

When signing in I would retrieve and check it using something like php's `password_verify()` - but in JS!

Is there anything like this?

I don't use node.js (not even a real server architecture) but crypto.js on client side

Comment: Do you use nodejs?

Comment: You want to do password hashing and storing *client side, in the browser?!* Can you paint a bigger picture what you're trying to do with that exactly?

Comment: @Alex no i don't

Comment: And I want to use the users password to encrypt the data. Also the users should sign in as a troll could decrypt the data instead

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing built into JavaScript itself, but the web platform provides the Web Crypto API ([spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/WebCryptoAPI/), [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Crypto_API)). The parts you want are only available in [secure contexts](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Secure_Contexts) (e.g., pages served with `https` or locally) via the [`Crypto.subtle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Crypto/subtle) property referring to a [`SubtleCrypto`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto) instance. It offers hashing via the [`digest` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/digest), etc.

---

You probably know this, but storing the notes and the hashed password in the browser's local storage is unlikely to keep them secure. Instead of storing the hashed password, I'd *encrypt* the notes using the password the user supplies (or something like that), and not store a hash of the password. (The `Crypto.subtle` object has [`encrypt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/encrypt) and [`decrypt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto/decrypt) methods.) The notes can then only be decrypted by supplying the corect password (or, of course, breaking the encryption).

Take note of the warnings on the MDN pages related to this API. It's very, very easy to get this wrong.

Answer (score 2):

If you use node there are 2 solutions

- password-hash
- bcrypt

**password-hash**

Install it

```
npm install password-hash
```

Example

```
var passwordHash = require('password-hash');

    var hashedPassword = passwordHash.generate('password123');

    console.log(hashedPassword); // sha1$3I7HRwy7$cbfdac6008f9cab4083784cbd1874f76618d2a97
```